# What type of facebook auth/token do I need for this?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to build a custom asp.net control to put on a webpage that will allow people to see a piece of information from my facebook account that requires auth.  For the sake of simplicity let's just say I'd like it to display the last thing that I liked.  I don't want the visitor to my site to have to be logged into facebook (nor would they have to be my friend on fb).  I want my site to somehow store a token that I have authorized and then it will use this token for the access.  I know this can be done initially, but I'm confused what happens when the token expires.  Or for that matter if I log out from facebook.  Is there some type of token or secret or something that I can request that can be auto-renewed again and again by my website independent of any login state that I have as an fb user?  Does this require me creating an fb app and associating the token to it?

I don't have any code at this point, I'm looking for a higher level of guidance on the protocol that should be used here, from there I can hopefully figure out the code from existing samples, docs, etc.  This is my first code interaction with facebook so don't assume that I know very much at this point :-)

EDIT:  I've been reading everything I can about this topic and I can't seem to find a solution.  In the past there was an RSS feed but that appears to be gone now.  Then there was also the offline_access permission which is no longer available.  This seems like such a simple task but I'm just not able to connect the dots.  I have been able to get the initial user token with perms for reading "likes", that's easy.  Now I can store that in my website's db and use it to make requests for that data anytime someone loads my page.  But eventually the token will expire and I'm not seeing any automatic way to renew it that wouldn't potentially involve user "Larry", who happens to be browsing my website, being asked to supply MY facebook credentials.  Basically it seems as though I could never log out from facebook or I'd be risking a broken feed on my website.  Is the fb auth model just not set up to allow for thist?  To summarize again - a user Bob wants to give his permission to acme.com to always be able to display Bob's most recent like regardless of whether Bob is logged in to fb or not.  He would only want to have this stop working if he revoked authorization to the WhatDoesBobLike app which runs on acme.com.  Possible?

-JT

Answer (score 0):

You would need an extended access token. It will only last up to 60 days and from then you would need to re-extend.

If it were a page you could extend the user access token then grab the page access token which would never expire.

Read more at

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: But won't that have the same issues, just 60 days down the road instead of 2 hours?  Specifically, the fb docs say the token you are trying to exchange/extend must be non-expired.  So if I do the initial auth today and store off that token and then nobody visits my site for 70 days, when a random visitor finally comes it won't be able to extend the token without me signing in again, right?

Comment: Still haven't been able to find a foolproof solution here.  Seems almost like I'd need a background process to periodically acquire a new token prior to the existing one expiring.  Is that crazy?